# WCF Service for Multiple clients with database(each for client)

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF service to get data from database and it's working fine with single client.

Now we want to move our application over cloud and share same WCF service there with different clients and databases (database is unique for each client and is hosted on X server).

We set service behavior to `ConcurrencyMode.Single` and `InstanceContextMode.PerSession`

There is one private object which connected with Business layer and calls different WCF calls.
We want to this object unique for each WCF service client.

And we want to host this on console application.

Anyone please help us to short out this issue or any other way to get this.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, M.azhar have u find any solution for this ?